# Windows Store App XAML - How to get textbox value of navigated page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal, windows-store

Windows Store App XAML - How to get textbox value of navigated page.i have 2 pages 
1.MainPage.xaml
2.Infopage.xaml
in the MainPage i have a Button(to get TextBox value of InfoPage) and a frame(to navigate InfoPage).. 
in the InfoPage there are some TextBoxes..now how can i get InfoPage TextBox values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In additional to Neal’s solution, here is another two ways you can also reference.

One way is to define a static parameter on `infoPage` and set the value to current page. Then you can invoke the method on `infoPage` from `MainPage`. Code like follows:

`infoPage`

```
 public static InfoPage Current;
 public InfoPage()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent();
     Current = this;      
 }
public string gettext()
{
    return txttext.Text;
}
```

`MainPage`

```
private void btngetsecondpage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InfoPage infopage = InfoPage.Current;
    txtresult.Text = infopage.gettext();  
}
```

More details about `ApplicationData` please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ApplicationData).

Another way is to save the text temporary in [ApplicationData.LocalSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) on `infoPage` and read the text out on the `MainPage`. Code like follows:

`infoPage`

```
private void txttext_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    localSettings.Values["texboxtext"] =txttext.Text; // example value            
}
```

`MainPage`

```
 private void btngetsecondpage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 { 
     ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
     if (localSettings.Values["texboxtext"] != null)
     {
         txtresult.Text = localSettings.Values["texboxtext"].ToString();
     }
 }
```

If you have a large amount of data, a better way is to create a local file as database, and use a MVVM pattern to write data into local file from `infoPage` and bind data which saved in the database to `MainPage`. More details about MVVM in uwp you can reference [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/020f8f/universal-windows-platform-with-mvvm/) .

Comment: wow! my problem solved by doing this 
1st page code :
 public static FormFillPersonalinfo Current;
        public FormFillPersonalinfo()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Current = this;
        }
        public string ffptitle()
        {
            return (Title.SelectedItem as FlipViewItem).Content.ToString();
        }
        public string ffpfirstname()
        {
            return FirstName.Text;
        }

Comment: 2nd page code : 
private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            mm.Text = FormFillPersonalinfo.Current.ffpbirthday();
        }

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to store the value from the InfoPage to the global variable inside the App object and then retrieve it in the MainPage.

In the app.xaml.cs, define a string or List,

```
public string commonValue;
```

In the InfoPage

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox Name="tb1" Text="Hello"/>
```

In the InfoPage code behind, we store the value of textbox to the app.

```
        public InfoPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        App app = Application.Current as App;
        app.commonValue = tb1.Text;
    }
```

Then in the MainPage:

```
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="MainPage" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TextBox Name="textbox1"/>
```

In the MainPage code behind, we need to initialize the InfoPage then retrieve the value:

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        InfoPage info = new InfoPage();
        info.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App app = Application.Current as App;
        textbox1.Text = app.commonValue;
    }
}
```